# How to fix 'HttpException' error while running flutter app on an Android Emulator with Android Q?

Tags: android, flutter, android-10.0

I'm trying to run flutter app on Android Emulator Pixel 2 running on Android Q, but the command `flutter run` throws the following error:

```
Error connecting to the service protocol: HttpException: Connection closed before full header was received, uri = http://127.0.0.1:64350/YLIiMby5lk4=/ws
```

I tried restarting Android Studio as well as the emulator.
As per solutions found on Github Issues and Stackoverflow I also tried adding `NO_PROXY=localhost,127.0.0.1` to `.bash_profile`

Answer (score 0):

For the android emulator use `10.0.2.2` instead of `127.0.0.1`. So try  http://10.0.2.2/YLIiMby5lk4=/ws
If you are using a `real device` replace this with your `Computers Ip address`

Comment: I did change it in `.bash_profile` to `NO_PROXY=localhost,10.0.2.2` but didn't work.